# Configure session cookie name in Grizzly

Tags: java, session-cookies, grizzly

I'm using Grizzly 2.3.24 as standalone webserver for my application. Since [Grizzly-1798](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1798) has been closed, I'd like to implement my own SessionManager. But it seems, I'm lacking the configuration option to set the default session cookie name.

What works is setting the desired cookie name just before I obtain the session, but that seems kinda crazy, no?

Here an example accessing the session in a Jersey resource:

```
@GET
public Response testGetSession(@Context Request request) {
    request.setSessionCookieName("mySessionCookie");

    Session session = request.getSession();
    log.info("Got session id {}", session.getIdInternal());

    return Response.ok().entity("hallo").build();
}
```

If I don't specify it with `request.setSessionCookieName()`, it defaults to `JSESSIONID`.

I understand, it'd be possible to do this in a `RequestFilter` for all requests, but do I really need to go down that path?

My expectation was that the `SessionManager` would be responsible for defining the cookie name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I believe this to be a bug. I have filed [GRIZZLY-1877](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1877).

---

**Update:**

[GRIZZLY-1877](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1877) has been resolved and version [2.3.30](https://grizzly.java.net/dependencies.html) is available for download and in maven central.

As a result, the workaround below is no longer necessary. Simply implementing `SessionManager#getSessionCookieName()` fixes the situation.

---

**Old workaround:**

In the meantime (or if v2.3.30 is not an option), I have a workaround, using Jersey's `ContainerRequestFilter` to set the session cookie name for each `Request`:

```
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;

/**
 * Until the session cookie can be defined in the Grizzly {@link HttpServer},
 * it will be set here.
 * <p>
 * The filter's priority ensures it gets executed before filters with 
 * {@link Priorities#AUTHENTICATION}.
 * 
 * @author hank
 */
@Provider
@Priority(300)  // less than 1000
@PreMatching
public class SessionCookieFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    javax.inject.Provider<Request> requestProvider;

    @Inject
    Config config;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Request request = requestProvider.get();
        request.setSessionCookieName(config.getSessionCookieName());
    }

}
```